# Converting Screen Coordinates to Complex Coordinates

Tags: c#, c++, fractals, mandelbrot

Can someone please show me how to convert from screen coordinates to complex? This picture shows the specific details about conversion
[image]

Providing with the steps of how you get a relationship between the two would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question. That asside, are you sure you want `-2` in the top left corner, and not `-1` ?

Comment: yeh im sure its -2 and not -1

Comment: Explore User Defined Literals

Comment: there is a complex type in  system.numerics

Comment: You could use Linear Algebra and use a scaling and transformation matrix.  You may be able to combine them into one matrix.

Comment: You should be a lot clearer as to what you really want; sometimes words sound simple but hide the real problems. To transform coordinates you need nothing more than simplest arithmetic, but this will still not transform real 2d into complex numbers.. For a Graphics object G you could use `Matrix M = new Matrix();  M.Scale(1f / this.Width, 1f / this.Height);   M.Translate(-2, -1);  G.MultiplyTransform(M);` I think writing a few transformation functions will be better; separate the calculation and the display, aka model-view!

Answer (score 1):

**Screen -> Complex**

Conversion:

```
screenPointX .. X coordinate on the screen  
screenPointY .. Y coordinate on the screen  
screenWidth  .. width of the screen  
screenHeight .. height of the screen  
re           .. real component of resulting complex
im           .. imaginary component of resulting complex

re = 3 * screenPointX / screenWidth - 2
im = 1 - 2 * screenPointY / screenHeight
```

Example `C++` implementation:

```
template<class T>
std::complex<T> screenToComplex(
    T screenPointX,
    T screenPointY,
    T screenWidth,
    T screenHeight)
{
    T re = 3 * screenPointX / screenWidth - 2;
    T im = 1 - 2 * screenPointY / screenHeight;
    return std::complex<T>(re, im);
}
```

Just rearrange for the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

```
Screen coordinate [0,0]          -> Complex coordinate [-2, 1]  
Screen coordinate [width,height] -> Complex coordinate [1, -1]

Screen X coordinate [x]          -> Complex coordinate [-2 + 3*x/width]  
Screen Y coordinate [y]          -> Complex coordinate [1  - 2*y/height]
```

Comment: Use `y/height` instead of `x/height`.